# TableView expand and collapse cells in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hi I've watched a tutorial about this issue and I can open and close tapped sections in my table view, but if a section is open and I am going to open another section, I want the previous one to be closed, but I can't.

**TableViewCodes**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    let section = sections[section]
    
    if section.isOpened {
        return section.options.count + 1
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    
    return sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerCell", for: indexPath) as? HeaderView else {return UITableViewCell()}
        cell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607108235, green: 0.9608257413, blue: 0.9606716037, alpha: 1)
        
        cell.titleLabel?.text = sections[indexPath.section].title
        return cell
        
    } else {
        
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
        cell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607108235, green: 0.9608257413, blue: 0.9606716037, alpha: 1)
        
        cell.titleLabel?.text = sections[indexPath.section].options[indexPath.row - 1]
        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {  
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    sections[indexPath.section].isOpened = !sections[indexPath.section].isOpened
    tableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], with: .none)
}
```

**Section Model**

```
class Section {
    
    let title: String
    let options: [String]
    var isOpened: Bool = false
    
    init(title: String, options: [String], isOpened: Bool = false) {
        
        self.title = title
        self.options = options
        self.isOpened = isOpened
    }
}
```

**ViewDidLoad**

```
sections = [
    
    Section(title: "Spor Giyim 1", options: [1,2,3].compactMap({ return "Cell \($0)" }), isOpened: true),
    Section(title: "Spor Giyim 2", options: [1,2,3].compactMap({ return "Cell \($0)" }), isOpened: false),
    Section(title: "Spor Giyim 3", options: [1,2,3].compactMap({ return "Cell \($0)" }), isOpened: false),
    Section(title: "Spor Giyim 4", options: [1,2,3].compactMap({ return "Cell \($0)" }), isOpened: false)
    
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset them all to `false` then toggle the current state of the clicked section

```
let toSet = !sections[indexPath.section].isOpened
sections.forEach {
    $0.isOpened = false
}
sections[indexPath.section].isOpened = toSet
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Replaced my Didselect function with your code, it worked, thank you, but how can I do this with animation.

Comment: I use tableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], with: .none) but app has crashed @Sh_Khan

Answer (score 0):

Store a reference to any open section in the viewController, use this to reset it to closed, and then reload both that section and the one you want to open:

```
class myVC: UIViewController {
  var openSection: Int?
  // rest of the VC...
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {  
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    if let openSection = openSection, openSection != indexpath.section {
       section[openSection].isOpened = false
       section[indexPath.section].isOpened = true
       tableView.reloadSections([ openSection, indexPath.section], with: .automatic)
       openSection = indexPath.section
    } else {
      sections[indexPath.section].isOpened.toggle()
      tableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], with: .automatic)
      openSection = sections[indexPath.section].isOpened ? indexPath.section : nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer actually @Sh_Khans 's answer solved my problem, but there is no animation. I need it to be animated.

Comment: The above will give the standard table view animation (as will @Sh_Khans, depending how you implement it). You could also (if you’re IOS 13+) use the diffable data source APIs which also animate. 
If you want custom animations then that’s a completely different question.

Comment: oh, thank you my ios target is 10.0 but I took care of animation problem somehow